# Does `declare -a A` create an empty array `A` in Bash?

Tags: bash, variable, array, declare

Does `declare -a A` create an empty array `A` in bash, or does it just set an attribute in case `A` is assigned to later?

Consider this code:

```
set -u
declare -a A
echo ${#A[*]}
echo ${A[*]}
A=()
echo ${#A[*]}
echo ${A[*]}
A=(1 2)
echo ${#A[*]}
echo ${A[*]}
```

What should be the expected output?

In Bash 4.3.48(1) I get `bash: A: unbound variable` when querying the number of elements after `declare`.
I also get that error when accessing all the elements.
I know that later versions of Bash treat this differently.
Still I'd like to know whether `declare` actually *defines* a variable (to be empty).

Comment: Well, you could try `declare -a P; Q=()`, then `declare -p P Q` or `set | grep -w '^[PQ]'` to show bash's idea of your variables. Does this satisfy you or are you looking for something deeper?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That depends whether the corresponding variable has already been declared in the current scope (top-level aka global or current function) before.

If it hasn't been declared in the current scope (and beware that in the top-level scope, the variable may have *declared* (and assigned) by importing it from the environment), then it declares it (makes it local to the function when in function scope), assigning it a type, but doesn't initialise it, not even to an empty list (`declare -p a` shows `declare -a a`, not `declare -a a=()` as it would if you had declared and/or assigned it with `a=()`).

If it had already been declared in the current scope (for instance because it was imported as a scalar variable from the environment when in the global scope), then `declare -a a` would try to *convert* it to an array.

If it was previously a scalar, then it becomes a `([0]=value-of-the-variable)` array. If it was already an array, it is left untouched. If it was an associative array, it fails with a `cannot convert associative to indexed array` error.

Note that `declare a` would not convert an array or hash to scalar. `bash` would not be able to convert a hash/array to scalar anyway. You can use `declare +aA a` to force a scalar (that would fail with an error if the variable was previously a hash/array in the current scope).

In your case, the variable was probably not already declared in the current scope, so it ended up declared but not assigned which explains why trying to expand it fails under `set -u`.

That distinction between two *declared* and *assigned*/*set* states of a variable is not specific to `bash`. In POSIX `sh`, you can also `export` a variable or make it `readonly` without giving it a value.

```
$ sh -uc 'unset -v var; readonly var; : "$var"'
sh: 1: var: parameter not set
```

Note that `unset` both unsets and undeclares the variable. In `bash`, `mksh` and `yash` it may restore the variable from an outer scope.

In `zsh`, except in `sh` emulation, using `typeset` on a variable declares and sets it to an empty value if it was not already set or was set but from a different type (scalar vs array vs associative array).

Comment: So my conclusion is that when `A` is undeclared before `declare -a A`, then `A` still is no array (because otherwise it would be an **empty array** with 0 elements), but undefined. So what's the purpose of `declare -a` when I can create arrays by assignment (`A=()`, `A[0]=...`)?

Comment: @U.Windl: The `declare -a` /`declare -A` are just to differentiate if you want to use the array with name following as an indexed or an associative array. Neither of them set/initialize values

Comment: @U.Windl, it still declares it as a array so that for instance `a=foo` would do `a[0]=foo` and `declare -p a` would show it as an array. But the main usage of `declare` in in function to make the function local to the function. It's like for `export`, it doesn't assign it but remembers the `export` attribute in case the variable is assigned later.